# forEach() is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am getting an error during the page load
I think true code but console declare warning forEach() is not a function
Help me please if you have time. Thank you for the help.

```
function duty() {
  let tasks;

  if (localStorage.getItem("tasks") === null) {
    tasks = [];
  } else {
    tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
  }

  tasks.forEach(function (item) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");

    li.className = "collection-item";

    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));

    const link = document.createElement("a");

    link.className = "delete-item secondary-content";
    link.innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-trash'></i>";

    li.appendChild(link);

    taskList.appendChild(li);
  });
}
```

Comment: It looks like the values stored in your local storage isn't parsed as an array. Add `console.log(tasks);` before the forEach line to inspect the value.

Comment: oke , I can try your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
```

Result of this line is not an Array it's an object and forEach works only on the Array.

Comment: I can try change my code found your suggestion. Thank your suggestion

Comment: Your suggestion is true . Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values(obj)` to convert the object to an array, then proceed with `forEach()`

Comment: [`JSON.parse(...)` returns many types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#return_value), so the appropriate transformations may vary depending on what's coming out. It seems more likely the question asker meant for the JSON to contain an array but wrote the wrong value.